# Python templates

Tags: python, django

This is my views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context
def login(request):
    t = get_template('login.html')
    return HttpResponse(t.render)
```

In my urls.py I put

```
(r'^login/', include('project.views.login')),
```

to show my templates

I set my templates directory in settings.py

But i got an error named

```
ImportError at /login/
No module named login
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: It would help if you'd elaborate a bit on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: i want to use my login.html login.html is in templates directory but i  got this error :S

Comment: can you please paste here your settings file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs) is used to include other url configs from other apps. It shouldn't be used if you're trying to add a url pattern for one particular view. You should have something like

```
(r'^login/', 'project.views.login'),
```

The other problem is where you return your response. `render` is a method that takes a context (see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context))

```
def login(request):
    t = get_template('login.html')
    c = Context({})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

In practice, you wouldn't usually load the template, render it, then return a response. There are two shortcut functions, [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) and [`render_to_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response), that cut down on repetition.

You've made a few basic mistakes here. I recommend you work through the Django tutorials (again, if you've already looked at them). [Tutorial 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/) in particular explains all this stuff.

Comment: i take only ">" as an output :S

Comment: its name is login but index page :D

Comment: what the meaning of ">"  in browser i see ">" this as output